# UITableView reloadData lose elements from cell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8, reloaddata

I have a UITableView and his datasource is an NSMutableArray declared in my interface:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arrElements;
```

Now I implemented a simple "load more" in this way:

```
    - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    float endScrolling = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height;
    if (endScrolling >= scrollView.contentSize.height)
    {
        //only if i have others results i will call load more
        if([self.items_amount integerValue] > self.arrElements.count) {

            if(DEBUG_MODE == 1) {
                NSLog(@"Load more");
            }

            //get start param from array size and call load more
            NSNumber *start = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:([self.arrElements count]+1)];
            NSArray *passParams = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.menuItem,start,[NSNumber numberWithInteger:NUM_RESULTS_FOR_PAGE], nil];
            [self performSelector:@selector(loadMore:) withObject:passParams afterDelay:0.1];

        }
    }
}
```

and this is my loadMore method:

```
//load more elements
- (void)loadMore:(NSArray *)arrParams {

    //(MenuItem *)menuItem startingFrom:(NSNumber *)start numResults:(NSNumber *)results;

    MenuItem *menuItem  = [arrParams objectAtIndex:0];
    NSNumber *start     = [arrParams objectAtIndex:1];
    NSNumber *results    = [arrParams objectAtIndex:2];

    if(DEBUG_MODE == 1) {
        NSLog(@"Before load more %lu", (unsigned long)[self.arrElements count]);
    }

    //call API and parse it
    WebServicesClient *restClient = [[WebServicesClient alloc] init];
    NSData *data = [restClient callWorkAPI:[menuItem pathAPI] inLanguage:[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0] withLat:self.latitude withLng:self.longitude startingFrom:start numRows:results];
    for(Work* work in [[restClient parseWorks:data] objectForKey:@"items"]) {
        [self.arrElements addObject:work];
    }

    if(DEBUG_MODE == 1) {
        NSLog(@"After load more %lu", (unsigned long)[self.arrElements count]);
    }

    [self.tableElem reloadData];

}
```

And this is my custom cell:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier;
        CellIdentifier = @"HomeCell";

        HomeCell *cell = (HomeCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if(!cell) {
            cell = [[HomeCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        Work *work = (Work *)[[self arrElements] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.labelTitleItem.text = [work title];
        cell.labelSubtitleItem.text = @"my category"


        //if exists image
        if([[work image] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]] && [[work image] length] > 0) {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
                NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[work image]]];
                if ( data == nil )
                    return;
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    cell.imageItem.image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
                });
            });

        } else {
            //remove image setting height to 0
            [cell.imageItem setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.imageItem.frame.origin.x, cell.imageItem.frame.origin.y, cell.imageItem.frame.size.width, 0)];
        }


        if([[work distance] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
            [cell.imagePriority setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
            cell.labelDistanceItem.text = [self convertDistance:[work distance]];
            cell.labelDistanceItem.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        } else {
            //remove image setting height to 0
            [cell.imagePriority setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.imagePriority.frame.origin.x, cell.imagePriority.frame.origin.y, cell.imagePriority.frame.size.width, 0)];
            //remove label distance setting height to 0
            [cell.labelSubtitleItem setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.labelSubtitleItem.frame.origin.x, cell.labelSubtitleItem.frame.origin.y, cell.labelSubtitleItem.frame.size.width, 0)];
        }

        return cell;

    }

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[self arrElements] count];
}
```

Now the problem is that after reloadData i lose the text of a UILabel (my category) of my CustomCell
please, Any suggests?

Comment: Hey man can we see your cellforrowatindexpath and numberofsections

Comment: i debugged more and i discovered that i have the problem also if i call reloadData when i press a button :(

Comment: sry im late just left work. In cellforrow try checking if the indexpath.row is equal to your arrElements count minus 1 and then call that loadMore method.
Then try dragging your tableview up, cellforrow method should be called.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems with TalbeViews. Try using the method

`- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(RCGameTableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

to add the elements that you want. Keep the cell initialization that you do at the beginning of cellForRowAtIndexPath, but then return the cell right after and set the background color, labels, images, etc. in the `willDisplayCell` delegate function I mentioned.